# Formula to convert $1$ to $90$, $2$ to $180$?

Tags: trigonometry

Really quick question about Trig!

If I've got $\sin^{-1}(1)$ or $\sin^{-1}(2)$, how would I convert that to $90^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ ?

I'm trying to convert a graphed version of $f(x) = \sin(x)$ in the domain $0 \leq x \leq 360$ with all intersections of $\sin(x) = 0.371$ from the first intersection being $(0.38,0.371)$ to be $(\text{degree}, 0.371)$

Thank you! Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: First note that $\sin^{-1}(2)$ is not possible because $-1 \leq \sin{x} \leq 1$. Next take $y = \sin^{-1}(1) \Rightarrow \sin(y) =1 \Rightarrow y = \frac{\pi}{2}$ as one of the value

Comment: $\arcsin(2)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln(2+\sqrt 3)$ is [a complex number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ArcSin[2]), and thus cannot be the same as $180^\circ$. $\arcsin(1)$ will yield either $90^\circ$ or $\pi/2$, depending on the setting of your computing environment. In any event, it is a simple matter to convert radians to degrees. We have the relation $\pi\text{ radians}=180^\circ$.

Comment: basically I'm asking how I convert the 1 to 90 and the 2 to 180 in a picture like this :) http://www.bbc.co.uk/scotland/learning/bitesize/standard/maths_ii/images/sinx_and_0_75.gif thank you!

Comment: I see neither a 1 nor a 2 on the axes in the picture you've linked to.

Comment: I'm sorry* I meant vice versa* in the event that x=90, how would that be converted to x=1? sorry for the confusion!

Comment: thanks for all the responses! I just figured out your first answer, J.M! thank you! deg=rad/(180/pi)

Comment: Multiply, not divide, David.

Answer (score 2):

Let me venture a guess....  Since you've stated that $(0.38, 0.371)$ is a point on your graph of $y = \sin x$, your calculating device must be in *radians* mode.  Indeed, $\sin(0.38) = 0.371$.  Now the graph you've included as a link in the comments section shows $y = \sin x$ if the angle $x$ is measured in *degrees*.  So when you say you want to convert $(0.38, 0.371)$ to $(degree, 0.371)$, then all you need is the conversion factor,
$$ \mathrm{Degrees} = \mathrm{Radians} \times \frac{180^{\circ}}{\pi} $$

In particular, $0.38 \times \frac{180^{\circ}}{\pi} \approx 21.77^{\circ}$.

(Note, what is confusing about your post is your mention of $\sin^{-1} 1$ and
$\sin^{-1} 2$, which have nothing to do with the rest of the stated question.
Moreover, your graph shows the intersections of $y = \sin x$ with the line $y = 0.75$, so did you really mean to ask about the $x$-value(s) when $y = 0.75$?)

Hope this helps!